# Why are imported modules on serverless functions undefined?

Tags: javascript, serverless, vite, vercel

*TL;DR - why do imports return `undefined`? Especially for native Node modules like `path`?*

I have a [very small test application](https://github.com/qodesmith/vite-vercel-example), built with Vite, that has a single endpoint in the `/api` directory. I created this just to play around with Vite + Vercel.

I have only 2 module imports for my endpoint - `path` and `fs-extra`. Both are returning as `undefined`. I was getting `cannot read join of undefined` errors with the `path` module, so I wrapped everything in a `try/catch` just to see if the endpoint responds. It does. See my code below.

```js
import type {VercelRequest, VercelResponse} from '@vercel/node'
import path from 'node:path' // I've also tried 'path'
import fs from 'fs-extra'

export default function handler(req: VercelRequest, res: VercelResponse) {
  // Both of these log 'undefined' on my Vercel dashboard for function logs.
  console.log('path module:', path)
  console.log('fs module:', fs)

  try {
    // https://vercel.com/guides/how-can-i-use-files-in-serverless-functions
    const pathFromProjectRootToFile = '/api/usersData.json'
    const usersDataFilePath = path.join( // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR HAPPENS 
      process.cwd(),
      pathFromProjectRootToFile
    )
    const usersData = fs.readJSONSync(usersDataFilePath)
    res.json({users: usersData})
  } catch (e) {
    res.json({error: errorToObject(e as Error)})
  }
}

function errorToObject(err?: Error): Record<string, string> | null {
  if (!err || !(err instanceof Error)) return null

  const obj: Record<string, string> = {}

  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(err).forEach(prop => {
    const value = err[prop as keyof Error]

    if (typeof value !== 'string') return

    obj[prop] = value
  })

  return obj
}
```

As an aside, instead of `node:path` I also tried just `path`, but same thing - `undefined`. And I do have `fs-extra` as a dependency in my `package.json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deploying a Vite app on Vercel and utilizing the `/api` directory for a back end with Serverless Functions, *Node* modules need to be imported via `require`, not `import`. The `import` syntax works for types and *local* modules. See [this answer](https://github.com/vercel/community/discussions/893#discussioncomment-3756470) (and conversation) in Vercel's community discussions.

```js
import type {VercelRequest, VercelResponse} from '@vercel/node'
import localModule from '../myLocalModule'

const path = require('path')
const fsOriginal = require('fs')
const fs = require('fs-extra')

// Rest of the file here...
```

Comment: That's a horrible limitation, if true. Are you sure that user (amyegan) speaks for Vercel? I'd be keen to see an official comment from Vercel on this, since frankly it seems very unlikely.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Amy is the community manager over at Vercel, so she's official. I asked about documentation too and was told it doesn't exist (yet). See this comment from the thread I linked in my answer - https://github.com/vercel/community/discussions/893#discussioncomment-3756675

Comment: I read that, but I didn't (and don't) see anything saying she's speaking for Vercel. I would have expected something on her profile, for instance. Just because she uses "we," I'm not going to assume she speaks for Vercel. (I'm not saying I don't believe you. :-) Just that I don't see anything there I could infer it from.)

Comment: I think the title is on her LinkedIn profile. In the Github discussion forum, her name has the "Maintainer" bubble next to it. That plus the fact that she's been answering a ton of questions makes me think she officially speaks for Vercel. But maybe not. Either way, all I know is she helped me find a solution!